# Is it safe to use Javascript Decorators in production?

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I'm having a little trouble keeping up with the decorators in javascript.

I would really like to use them for my React Native project, it would allow me to have a more readable code.

But is it safe to use the Pure Javascript decorators for the moment (year 2020)? When EcmaScript says that decorators could have breaking changes in the future, what do they mean by that ?

I've already seen some people using decorators but with Typescript, do I have to use Typescript to have a "Stable" version of the decorators?

Comment: a breaking change, is a change, that breaks your code and makes its execution fail.

Comment: If my application is embedding the version of the decorators before the major change, there won't be any problem in my project, but only if I decide to update the decorators for a future version of the project, am I wrong?

Comment: well.. as long as you do transpiling and don't rely on browsers to parse the decorators, you would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Pure javascript" decorators don't exist (yet). The proposal for decorators is still in [stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), so it's not available in any browser or Node.

You can only use decorators through [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). A lot of popular TS based tools, such as Angular, use them. Whether you want to use them in production is really up to you, there is not objective way to decide that.